# Zero arity in Scala

Tags: scala

Tried this in Eclipse worksheet (2.10.1):

```
def a = { println("In a"); 3 }                    //> a: => Int
def b() = { println("In b"); 3 }                  //> b: ()Int
val c = () => { println("In c"); 3 }              //> c  : () => Int = <function0>

def test_type(x: => Int) = x                      //> test_type: (x: => Int)Int

test_type(a)                                      //> In a
                                                  //| res0: Int = 3

b()                                               //> In b
                                                  //| res1: Int = 3
c()                                               //> In c
                                                  //| res2: Int = 3

test_type(b)                                      //> In b
                                                  //| res3: Int = 3
// test_type(c) *** Doesn't compile
```

I'm definitely missing something. What's the difference between `a`, `b` and `c`? Looks to me that `a` is a "by-name" substitute for `val a = 3` (uniform access principle?) so I can't call `a()`, but why `b` and `c` have different types? I can call `b` without parenthesis too (i.e. `b` will be evaluated to a result) as well as `a`, and `b` will be converted to "by-name" when calling `test_type`, but `c` won't and `c` without parameters will be evaluated to the function itself (which looks reasonable).

And one more question, Martin Odersky in his online course is saying that any anonymous function like `() => 3` can be substituted with `{ def f() = 3; f }` if I got it right, but these two expressions have different types and evaluation rules, first will be evaluated to a function, second - to function result, e.g.:

```
val f2 = { def f() = 3; f }                       //> f2  : Int = 3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many cases where Scala treats methods and functions differently. The uniform access principle applies to method invocation, since methods are often used to mimic fields on objects, but not to function application.

While `b` is a *method* of type `()Int`, the code `b` will invoke the method when evaluated, *unless the compiler expected a function type where `b` was used*, in which case it will eta-expand the method to a function.

Since `c` is a *function* of type `() => Int`, applying it needs to be explicit in all contexts. So, `test_type(c())` should compile.

The "by-name"-ness of `x: => Int` doesn't affect these inference/application rules; it only affects *when* the parameter might be evaluated.

```
scala> object Foo {
     |   def f(): Int = 123
     |   val g: () => Int = () => 123
     | }
defined module Foo

scala> Foo.f
res0: Int = 123

scala> Foo.g
res1: () => Int = <function0>

scala> Foo.g()
res2: Int = 123

scala> (Foo.f: () => Int) // force eta-expansion by explicitly specifying function type
res3: () => Int = <function0>
```

Comment: Thank you, it helps. Why `a` can't be eta-expanded then? Looks to me that `a` can only be used where `Int` is expected. Which means Scala has pseudo-vals (is there a better name?) (`a`) behaving like "by-name" parameters, methods (`b`) that can be eta-expanded when required, and functions (`c`).

Comment: You can turn `a` into a function by following it with an underscore: `a _`

Comment: Which means that I can convert any expression into function with `def convert[A](x: => A) = x _`: `convert(3) //> res0: () => Int = <function0>`. Interesting idea.